# How to determine minimum edge thickness for a tapped hole?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

When having a tapped hole close to an edge in metal, how do you determine the minimum edge thickness around the tapped hole? Obviously the metal strength is a critical factor, but are there any rules of thumbs for common materials?

I could only find [a rule-of-thumb for tapped inserts](https://www.aboveboardelectronics.com/recoil-designs.html) that specifies:

> The minimum edge distance recommended is the maximum diameter of the STI tap measured from the edge of the material to the centre line of the hole.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance will be a function of the load applied by whatever is secured by that thread.

If the load is effectively negligible, then the positioning can be as close as possible without the cut threads breaking through the wall.

If the load is larger, then sufficient material around the hole must be allowed for, and if the load exceeds the strength of the threads in one hole then multiple holes or a different thread form may be considered.

Answer (score 1):

The European Standard EN 1993-1-8 *Eurocode 3:  Design  of  steel   structures  –
Part    1-8:    Design  of  joints* specifies a distance from the edge of at least 1.2 * d

For slot holes it specifies 1.5 * d.